# apply inside apply is good approach in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Lets say i have an object

```
class A{
    var name="Java"
    var age=26
    var gender="male"
    var address=Address()
}
class Address{
    var street ="Bakers street"
    var building = "221B"
    var city="London"
}
```

like this.
If I use apply inside apply like below

```
val actualA = A(
  actualA.apply {
            name="Kotlin"
           address.apply {
               street="No street"
               building="No building"
               city="Just another city"
           }
        }
```

Is it good practice to use apply inside apply?or any other scope function for that matter?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using [Type-Safe Builders](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html). Note that your second `apply` will never execute since the default value of `address` is `null` and you use `?.` without ever initializing `address`.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? Overuse of mutable state _is_ bad practice, though.

Comment: Thanks Alexey for the answer. I want to know why is it a bad practice? Does it create any overhead?

Comment: Where possible, prefer immutable state because it makes it easier to reason about an application. If something is immutable you don't have to worry about some random code changing the state unexpectedly and concurrency becomes less of a burden. That said, I _personally_ would not consider nested `apply` as shown in your example to be necessarily bad, though I don't have a lot of experience with Kotlin idioms. But you may still want to consider using _Type-Safe Builders_, depending on your use case (i.e. writing such builder code isn't necessarily worth it).